# Importar funções de outro arquivo(node.js)

Tags: node.js, importação, require

Tenho um arquivo bot.js que seria minha "main" do projeto e dentro da mesma pasta onde está o bot.js tenho Call.js e Somar.js que são apenas funções [call()] e [somar()]. Seria possível "importar" essas funções no bot.js e só usar somar() nele ao invés de ter que escrever a função no próprio arquivo bot.js?

Answer (score 2):

Pode sempre fazer `require` do arquivo em questão para poder utilizar o que ele tem, desde que tenha feito as exportações necessárias nele.

No `Somar.js` poderia fazer a exportação da função inteira, utilizando `module.exports`:

```
module.exports = (a, b) => a + b;
```

Depois no `bot.js` faria `require` para utilizar:

```
const somar = require('./Somar');
console.log(somar(10, 20)); //30
```

Note que no `require` tem de indicar o caminho onde se encontra o arquivo. Como se encontram na mesma pasta basta prefixar com `./`. É também importante mencionar que o `require` não leva a extensão do arquivo.

Também pode exportar mais do que uma função, se alterar a forma como exporta. A titulo de exemplo vamos assumir que no `Call.js` queria exportar duas funções.

Call.js

```
module.exports = {
    funcao1(){
        console.log("f1");
    },
    funcao2(){
        console.log("f2");
    }
}
```

Agora para utilizar estas funções também no `bot.js` faria assim:

```
const somar = require('./Somar');
console.log(somar(10, 20)); //30

const call = require('./Call');
call.funcao1(); //f1
call.funcao2(); //f2
```

Neste ultimo exemplo como a exportação é um objeto, tem de chamar as funções fazendo `call.funcao1()`.